# C Code Link Errors with an iPhone App

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, linker

I am having link errors when integrating a small number of C source files into an objective-c iOS project.

The C files were given to me by another developer who successfully used the code in c projects and in python projects.

When I add the c source code into the XCode project, the code compiles, but I get link errors after adding code in the objective c files to reference to C code. I get "duplicate symbol errors" for variables in the C code. This is when the objective c code has the .m extension.

When I change the objective c file to the .mm extension, I get "symbols not found for architecture i386" errors for the C functions I am calling from the objective c code.

There are many questions about C and objective C on forums, and I haven't found a solution yet. Any quick things to check?

Code snippets:

```
File: res.h

float Max_Std_Amp = 50;
void RD_Dispose(void);

File: res.c
void RD_Dispose(void) {
   Max_Std_Amp = 0;
}


File: Import.mm
#import "res.h"
void process(UInt32* data, UInt32 dataLength)
{
    RD_Dispose();
}
```

Link errors:

When Import.m has a .m extension:

```
duplicate symbol _Max_Std_Amp in:
    /Users/dayhacker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/My_Project-dbvpktweqzliaefgbqbebtdgyrey/Build/Intermediates/My Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Respitory Rate.build/Objects-normal/i386/Import.o
```

When Import.mm has a .mm extension:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "RD_Dispose()", referenced from:
 process(unsigned long*, unsigned long) in Import.o
```

Comment: Give specific examples of the error message. Are there actually function defined in your Objective-C code which have the same names as functions in the C code?

Comment: When objective c code has a ".mm" extension, XCode gives the following link error "Undefined symbols error: Apple Mach-O Linker Error, "RD_Dispose()", referenced from:"

In res.h, I have defined "void RD_Dispose(void)" and in RRimport.mm, I have a code block:

void process(UInt32* data, UInt32 dataLength)
{
    RD_Dispose();
}

Comment: You probably need to put more of your code up on your question, as well as the exact files the code you are posting is in!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have followed them and updated the question with a code snippet and the specific link errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res.h:

```
float Max_Std_Amp = 50;
```

That should be:

```
extern float Max_Std_Amp;
```

and the actual `float` defined in a source file (`res.c`):

```
float Max_Std_Amp = 50;
```

Otherwise `Max_Std_Amp` will be part of every source module that includes `res.h`, which is not what was intended.

If you want to use a C-function from C++ (`.mm` is Objective-C++), you need to declare the function as having C-linkage, like this:

res.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void RD_Dispose(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif
```

The above use of guard macros and C-linkage definition will allow the `res.h` header file to be included in both C and C++ (Objective-C and Objective-C++) source modules.

Comment: Trojanfoe, your solution works when the objective-c file uses the .m extension. Thanks! My app now links and runs, too.

Comment: Thanks, the #ifdef __cplusplus helped me out to get this working